# How can I save Google Cloud anchors for more than 24h?

Tags: api

I would like to save my Google Cloud anchor for more than 24h.

I have read the ARCore Cloud Anchor Management API documentation, but as a beginner, I am not sure what to do after "generating an OAuth2 token". Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Sorry for the lack of words, we are developing AR apps using Unity and Google Cloud Anchor. The documentation says that "keyless authentication" is required to keep the anchor for more than 24 hours, and I have followed the steps and built it, but I cannot open the app.